# Dimensional inconsistency in evaluating the canonical partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, dimensional-analysis, partition-function

We know that canonical partition of an $N$-particle system is given as
$$Z=\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\text{All possible microstates}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!e^{-\beta E}=\sum_E\Omega(E)e^{-\beta E}.$$

For a solid in 1D, through microcanonical ensemble, we have found
$$\Omega(E)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(N)}\Big(\frac{E}{\hbar\omega}\Big)^{N}.$$
So, $Z=\int dE\;\Omega(E)e^{-\beta E}$
$\implies Z=\frac{1}{\Gamma(N)}\Big(\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\Big)^{N}\int dE\;E^Ne^{-\beta E}$
$\implies Z=\frac{1}{\beta^{N+1}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(N)}\Big(\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\Big)^{N}\Gamma(N+1)=N\Big(\frac{k_BT}{\bar h\omega}\Big)^{N}(k_BT)$

For $N=1$,
$Z=\Big(\frac{k_BT}{\bar h\omega}\Big)(k_BT)$

We can see that the $Z$ is not dimensionless.
I think that $Z$ should be dimensionless.

Comment: Can you see where it stopped being dimensionless?

Comment: Yeah I can see that. It is in the step $Z=\int dE\Omega(E)e^{-\beta E}$. $dE$ has the unit of energy. I have a doubt that to make $dE$ dimensionless, should I divide by $K_BT$ or $\bar h\omega$

Comment: $Z$ is just a normalization factor: if you calculate any averages, they will have correct dimensions regardless of the dimensionality of $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

We have to be careful when we go from the discrete to the continuous domain. The dicrete partition function is
$$
   Z = \sum_E \Omega(E) e^{-\beta E}
$$
The corresponding continuous expression is
$$
  Z = \int \omega(E) e^{-\beta E} dE
$$
where $\omega(E)$ is the density of states per unit energy, namely $\omega(E) dE = d\Omega$ is the number of microstates in $(E, E+dE)$. This is also dimensionless, however, $\Omega$ and $\omega$ have different dimensions: $\Omega$ is dimensionless but $\omega$ has dimensions of 1/energy.

Because you used $\Omega$ instead of $\omega = d\Omega/dE$ you ended up with extra dimensions of energy in the numerator of the continuous partition function.